# Como hacer loop Foreach y reasignacion de valores al campo

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, angular

Tengo la siguiente duda, estoy realizando un formulario con `Angular` como Front y `Laravel` como Back, en donde agrego diferentes pasos junto con imagenes, todo funciona correctamente, la imagen la transformo a base 64 y en laravel modifico ciertas cosas, para transformarla y almacenarla en una carpeta, lo que no supe como hacer es una vez transformada y almacenada la imagen, como colocar la ruta en la que se almaceno en el campo correspondiente y asi asignarla para almacenarlo en la base de datos. Como puede ser desde 1 paso hasta 20, dichos pasos los almaceno en un json.

En angular lo tengo de la siguiente manera.

Mi formulario:

```
newProject = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [1],
  steps: this.formBuilder.array([this.newStep]),
})
```

La manera en como le asigno el array

```
get newStep(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    id: [this.getNewId()],
    paso: ['', Validators.required],
    accion: ['', Validators.required],
    punto: ['', Validators.required],
    razon: ['', Validators.required],
    fichero: ['', Validators.required]
  })
}
```

La manera en como transformo la imagen a base64

```
onChangeFile(input, index): void {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    // var img:any = new Image();
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(input.target.files[0]);

    this.steps.controls[index].value.namefile = input.target.files[0].name;
    var reader: any, target: EventTarget;
    reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
      img.src = event.target.result;
    console.log(img.src)
      this.steps.controls[index].value.fichero = img.src
    }, false);
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.target.files[0]);
  }
```

y cuando la recibo en Laravel le hago diferentes ajustes para transformarla y guardarla en una carpeta

```
$fileSteps = $params_array['steps'];
foreach ($fileSteps as $step) {
    $folderPath = "uploads/";
    $image_64 = $step['fichero'];
    $extension = explode('/', explode(':', substr($image_64, 0, strpos($image_64, ';')))[1])[1];
    $replace = substr($image_64, 0, strpos($image_64, ',')+1); 
    $image = str_replace($replace, '', $image_64); 
    $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
    $imageName = \Str::random(10).'.'.$extension;
    $fileStep = $folderPath . $imageName;
    file_put_contents($fileStep, base64_decode($image));            
    // $project->evidence = $file;
}
```

Asi es como llega mi formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero saber como asignarle a cada fichero su respectiva ruta terminando de transformarla y guardarla en la carpeta y donde dice fichero, ahi asignarle el valor que se creo en el foreach en el paso de `$fileStep = $folderPath . $imageName;`. Espero haberme explicado y que alguien me pueda ayudar

> Edicion añadido de codigo

Angular

file.component.ts

```
newProject = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [1],
  steps: this.formBuilder.array([this.newStep]),
})
getNewId() {
  this.currentStepId += 1;
  return this.currentStepId;
}

get newStep(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    id: [this.getNewId()],
    paso: ['', Validators.required],
    accion: ['', Validators.required],
    punto_critico: ['', Validators.required],
    razon: ['', Validators.required],
    fichero: ['', Validators.required]
  })
}
get steps(): FormArray {
  return this.newProject.get('steps') as FormArray
}

Addsteps() {
  this.steps.push(this.newStep);
}
onChangeFile(input, index): void {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  // var img:any = new Image();
  img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(input.target.files[0]);

  this.steps.controls[index].value.namefile = input.target.files[0].name;
  var reader: any, target: EventTarget;
  reader = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    img.src = event.target.result;
  console.log(img.src)
    this.steps.controls[index].value.fichero = img.src
  }, false);
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.target.files[0]);
}
```

file.componente.html

```
<form [formGroup]="newProject" autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-accordion class="example-headers-align" multi>

        <!-- PASOS A SEGUIR -->
        <mat-expansion-panel class="mb-1">
            <mat-expansion-panel-header class="disable_ripple">
                <mat-panel-title class="header-text">
                    Pasos a seguir
                </mat-panel-title>
                <mat-panel-description class="header-text">
                    Indique aqui los pasos para su correcta verificacion
                    <i class="material-icons">format_list_numbered</i>
                </mat-panel-description>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <hr />
            <div class="mt-4">
                <fieldset formArrayName="steps" class="col-12">
                    <fieldset class="container mb-4 p-3" name="steps"
                        *ngFor="let step of steps.controls; let i = index"
                        style="vertical-align: middle" [formGroupName]="i">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h4>Paso {{ i + 1 }}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <mat-form-field class="col-12">
                                    <mat-label>Paso</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="paso" />
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <mat-form-field class="col-12">
                                    <mat-label>Accion</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="accion" />
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <mat-form-field class="col-12">
                                    <mat-label>Punto critico</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="punto_critico" />
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <mat-form-field class="col-12">
                                    <mat-label>Razon</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="razon" />
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <mat-form-field class="col-md-12">
                                    <a mat-button class="btn-panel btn-block">
                                        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                                        <mat-label>Añadir evidencia</mat-label>
                                        <ngx-mat-file-input formControlName="fichero"
                                            placeholder="Basic Input" (change)="onChangeFile($event,i)">
                                        </ngx-mat-file-input>
                                    </a>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <a mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="removeStep(i)">Remover
                                    paso</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </fieldset>
                <a mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="Addsteps()">Agregar paso</a>
            </div>
        </mat-expansion-panel>

        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-md" [disabled]="!newProject.valid">
            ENVIAR
        </button>
    </mat-accordion>
</form>
```

Al hacer submit

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.newProject.value)
    this.abrirProyecto.createProject(this.token, this.newProject.value).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response)
      },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error)
      }
    )
  }
```

service.ts

```
createProject(token, formulario): Observable<any>{
        let json = JSON.stringify(formulario);
        let params = 'json=' + json;
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded').set('Authorization', token);
        return this.http.post(this.url + 'project', params, {headers:headers});
    }
```

> Codigo Laravel

```
    public function store(Request $request) {
            $hash = $request->header('Authorization', null);
    
            $json = $request->input('json', null);
            $params = json_decode($json);
            $params_array = json_decode($json, true);
    
            $jwtAuth = new JwtAuthSuperAdmin();
            $checkToken = $jwtAuth->checkToken($hash);
    
            if ($checkToken) {
                //Obtener usuario logeado
                $user = $jwtAuth->checkToken($hash, true);
    
                $validate = \Validator::make($params_array,[
                    'steps' => 'required',
                ]);
    
                if($validate -> fails()){
                    return $data = array(
                        'status' => 'error',
                        'message' => 'Al parecer algunos campos no son correctos o son requeridos',
                        'code' => 400
                    );
                }
    
                $project = new Project();
                $project->steps = $params->steps;
                
                $fileSteps = $params_array['steps'];
                foreach ($fileSteps as $key => $step) {
                    $folderPath = "uploads/";
                    $image_64 = $step['fichero'];
                    $extension = explode('/', explode(':', substr($image_64, 0, strpos($image_64, ';')))[1])[1];
                    $replace = substr($image_64, 0, strpos($image_64, ',')+1); 
                    $image = str_replace($replace, '', $image_64); 
                    $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
                    $imageName = \Str::random(10).'.'.$extension;
                    $fileStep = $folderPath . $imageName;
AGREGADO RECIENTEMENTE PERO SIN EXITO---->       $fileSteps[$key]['fichero'] = $fileStep;
                    file_put_contents($fileStep, base64_decode($image));
                }
    
                return $$project->save();
                die();
    
                if($project->save()){
                    $data = array(
                        'project' => $project,
                        'status' => 'success',
                        'message' => 'El proyecto se ha registrado correctamente.',
                        'code' => 200
                    );
                } else {
                    $data = array(
                        'status' => 'error',
                        'message' => 'Ha ocurrido un error, intentalo de nuevo.',
                        'code' => 400
                    );
                }
            } else {
                $data = array(
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'message' => 'Necesitas inicar sesion',
                    'code' => 400
                );
            }
    
            return response()->json($data, 200);
        }
```

> Agregado de imagen con nuevo error al tratar de guardar la informacion
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi es como recibo los pasos

```
steps: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código que usas para guardar en base de datos toda la información.

Comment: ok, en un momento edito la pregunta

Comment: @Triby listo, espero ayude

Comment: @Triby , ya consegui hacer lo que queria. pero ahora tengo un error de `"Array to string conversion"` al momento de querer guardar la informacion coloco una imagen de lo que recibo en el return con todos los datos que envio desde el formulario

Comment: Corrige el doble `$$` en `return $$project->save();`

Comment: @Triby ya lo corregi y sigue marcando error, acabo de adjuntar otra captura con el mensaje de error que me manda, pero es lo unico que me señala

Comment: me faltaba convertir con json_encode todos los campos que venian como arreglo o json